# What is Random seed in Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, random-seed, iris-dataset

I am learning Azure Machine Learning. I am frequently encountering the **Random Seed** in some of the steps like,

1. Split Data
2. Untrained algorithm models as Two Class Regression, Multi-class regression, Tree, Forest,..

In the tutorial, they choose Random Seed as '123'; trained model has high accuracy but when I try to choose other random integers like 245, 256, 12, 321,.. it did not do well.

---

**Questions**

- What is a Random Seed Integer?
- How to carefully choose a Random Seed from range of integer values? What is the key or strategy to choose it?
- Why does Random Seed significantly affect the ML Scoring, Prediction and Quality of the trained model?

---

**Pretext**

1. I have [Iris-Sepal-Petal-Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) with Sepal (*Length & Width*) and Petal (*Length & Width*)
2. Last column in data-set is 'Binomial ClassName'
3. I am training the data-set with Multiclass Decision Forest Algorithm and splitting the data with different random seeds 321, 123 and 12345 in order
4. It affects the final quality of trained model. Random seed#123 being best of Prediction probability score: 1.

[image: ML Studio Snap]

---

**Observations**

**1. Random seed: 321**

[image: Random-seed-321]

**2. Random seed: 123**

[image: Random-seed-123]

**3. Random seed: 12345**

[image: Random-seed-12345]

Comment: Please consider doing a simple search before rushing to ask here; random seed serves just to initialize the (pseudo)random number generator, mainly in order to make examples reproducible. You cannot actually choose it (carefully or not), in the sense that it is not supposed to have any effect in the results; whatever effects it may have, it is due to some random element inherent in processes such as splitting data. model initialization etc.

Comment: It's for reproducibility, so that someone else can run your code and verify your outputs! Even when you're using a 'random number'

Comment: @desertnaut, I have added my observations to the question. If I take random-seed is for reproducible, then it should not affect the accuracy of the prediction. But it does. So that, I had to wonder what is its significance and how to choose it carefully to highest accuracy?

Comment: Have already explained this - please read more closely

Comment: How many samples in your test set?

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, we choose any **random seed** in Split() module, just to make sure that prediction is same across repeated runs.

Comment: @desertnaut, only 150 rows are there. I am using Stratification in Split() module for splitting the rows evenly across different categories. (*which is 'Botanical Class Name in my case'*)

Comment: 150 rows is the *whole* dataset; evaluation is made on the test part of the split - so, how many rows in the *test* set (or what percentage did you ask for the test set in the split)?

Comment: @desertnaut, 80% of evenly distributed dataset for training and 20% of it to score or test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a Random Seed Integer?

Will not go into any details regarding what a random seed is in general; there is plenty of material available by a simple web search (see for example [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)).

Random seed serves just to initialize the (pseudo)random number generator, mainly in order to make ML examples reproducible.

> How to carefully choose a Random Seed from range of integer values? What is the key or strategy to choose it?

Arguably this is already answered implicitly above: you are simply not supposed to choose any particular random seed, and your results should be roughly the same across different random seeds.

> Why does Random Seed significantly affect the ML Scoring, Prediction and Quality of the trained model?

Now, to the heart of your question. The answer *here* (i.e. with the iris dataset) is the **small-sample effects**...

To start with, your reported results across different random seeds are not *that* different. Nevertheless, I agree that, at first sight, a difference in macro-average precision of 0.9 and 0.94 might *seem* large; but looking more closely it is revealed that the difference is really not an issue. Why?

Using the 20% of your (only) 150-samples dataset leaves you with only 30 samples in your test set (where the evaluation is performed); this is stratified, i.e. about 10 samples from each class. Now, for datasets of *that* small size, it is not difficult to imagine that a difference in the correct classification of **only 1-2** samples can have this apparent difference in the performance metrics reported.

Let's try to verify this in scikit-learn using a decision tree classifier (the essence of the issue does not depend on the specific framework or the ML algorithm used):

```python
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=321, stratify=y)
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = dt.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Result:

```
[[10  0  0]
 [ 0  9  1]
 [ 0  0 10]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
           1       1.00      0.90      0.95        10
           2       0.91      1.00      0.95        10

   micro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97        30
   macro avg       0.97      0.97      0.97        30
weighted avg       0.97      0.97      0.97        30
```

Let's repeat the code above, changing only the `random_state` argument in `train_test_split`; for `random_state=123` we get:

```
[[10  0  0]
 [ 0  7  3]
 [ 0  2  8]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
           1       0.78      0.70      0.74        10
           2       0.73      0.80      0.76        10

   micro avg       0.83      0.83      0.83        30
   macro avg       0.84      0.83      0.83        30
weighted avg       0.84      0.83      0.83        30
```

while for `random_state=12345` we get:

```
[[10  0  0]
 [ 0  8  2]
 [ 0  0 10]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
           1       1.00      0.80      0.89        10
           2       0.83      1.00      0.91        10

   micro avg       0.93      0.93      0.93        30
   macro avg       0.94      0.93      0.93        30
weighted avg       0.94      0.93      0.93        30
```

Looking at the *absolute numbers* of the 3 confusion matrices (in *small samples*, percentages can be **misleading**), you should be able to convince yourself that the differences are not that big, and they can be arguably justified by the random element inherent in the whole procedure (here the exact split of the dataset into training and test).

Should your test set be significantly bigger, these discrepancies would be practically negligible...

A last notice; I have used the exact same seed numbers as you, but this does not actually mean anything, as in general the random number generators *across* platforms & languages are not the same, hence the corresponding seeds are not actually compatible. See own answer in [Are random seeds compatible between systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293899/are-random-seeds-compatible-between-systems) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

The seed is used to initialize the pseudorandom number generator in Python.

The random module uses the seed value as a base to generate a random number. if seed value is not present it takes system current time. if you provide same seed value before generating random data it will produce the same data. refer  https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/ for more details.

Example:

```
import random
random.seed( 30 )
print ("first number  - ", random.randint(25,50))  

random.seed( 30 )
print ("Second number- ", random.randint(25,50))

Output:

first number - 42
Second  number - 42
```