# Why does random.seed( ) not work in generating dataset?

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-seed

I'm creating dataset for testing with

```
import random
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

random.seed(10)
X, y = make_regression(n_samples = 1000, n_features = 10)
X[0:2]
```

Could you please explain why I get a different dataset after each running? For example, 2 runs return

```
array([[-0.28058959, -0.00570283,  0.31728106,  0.52745066,  1.69651572,
        -0.37038286,  0.67825801, -0.71782482, -0.29886242,  0.07891646],
       [ 0.73872413, -0.27472164, -1.70298606, -0.59211593,  0.04060707,
         1.39661574, -1.25656819, -0.79698442, -0.38533316,  0.65484856]])
```

and

```
array([[ 0.12493586,  1.01388974,  1.2390685 , -0.13797227,  0.60029193,
        -1.39268898, -0.49804303,  1.31267837,  0.11774784,  0.56224193],
       [ 0.47067323,  0.3845262 ,  1.22959284, -0.02913909, -1.56481745,
        -1.56479078,  2.04082295, -0.22561445, -0.37150552,  0.91750366]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the seed into the `make_regression` call as parameter:

```
sklearn.datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=100, n_informative=10,
                                 n_targets=1, bias=0.0, effective_rank=None,
                                 tail_strength=0.5, noise=0.0, shuffle=True,
                                 coef=False, random_state= None )
                                             ^°^°^°^°^°^°^°^°^°
```

See [API](https://sklearn.org/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html):

> ***random_state*** : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
>
> If *int*, `random_state` is the seed used by the random number generator;
> If RandomState instance, `random_state` is the random number generator;
> If `None`, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by `np.random`.

So in your case:

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples = 1000, n_features = 10, random_state = 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Although setting the `random_state` argument in `make_regression`, as already suggested, resolves the issue, it would arguably be useful to clarify exactly the reason **why** your own code snippet does not work as expected. And the answer is that, as implied in the [docs](https://sklearn.org/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html), `make_regression` uses the random number generator (RNG) from Numpy, and not from the Python `random` module used in your code.

So, changing only slightly your code snippet to

```
import numpy as np # change 1
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

np.random.seed(10) # change 2
X, y = make_regression(n_samples = 1000, n_features = 10) # no random_state set here
X[0:2]
```

always results in the same dataset:

```
array([[-1.32553507, -1.34894938, -0.82160306,  0.03538905, -0.68611315,
        -0.74469132,  1.37391771,  0.98675482, -0.90921643, -1.57943748],
       [ 1.13660812,  0.52367005,  0.05090828, -0.47210149, -0.98592548,
        -0.69677968,  0.31752274, -0.0771912 ,  2.17548753,  0.75189637]])
```

which is actually identical with the one yielded with setting `random_state=10` in `make_regression`:

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples = 1000, n_features = 10, random_state=10)
X[0:2]

# result:

array([[-1.32553507, -1.34894938, -0.82160306,  0.03538905, -0.68611315,
        -0.74469132,  1.37391771,  0.98675482, -0.90921643, -1.57943748],
       [ 1.13660812,  0.52367005,  0.05090828, -0.47210149, -0.98592548,
        -0.69677968,  0.31752274, -0.0771912 ,  2.17548753,  0.75189637]])
```

For more on RNGs, you may find own answer in [Are random seeds compatible between systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293899/are-random-seeds-compatible-between-systems/52311492#52311492) useful.